# Solr suggest - context filtering with DocumentDictionaryFactory returns entire field

Tags: solr, autocomplete, autosuggest, solrconfig

I'm working on an autocomplete feature for an app that provides full text searching of books.

I'm trying to configure Solr (v.7.4.0) suggester with context filtering (e.g. limit results to text from pages of a single book) to return matching terms for a supplied query, but instead it returns the contents of the *entire field*.

In the definition for the searchComponent in solrconfig.xml, when I use FuzzyLookupFactory this works fine (returns single words), but that lookup implementation doesn't support context filtering. When I switch to AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory in combination with DocumentDictionaryFactory to support context filtering (see [Solr docs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/suggester.html#context-filtering)), I can the entire field is returned.

Example field value:

```
{
   "id":"abc1234",
   "ocrtext":"In choosing Colors for candy, certain qualifications are necessary. First, they must not fade or change"
}
```

In response to a query like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/iiif_suggest?wt=json&q=col&suggest.cfq=456789
```

What I want is:

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 1
    },
    "suggest": {
        "iiifSuggester": {
            "col": {
                "numFound": 1,
                "suggestions": [
                    {
                        "term": "colors",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "payload": ""
                    }]}}}
}
```

But what I get is:

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 1
    },
    "suggest": {
        "iiifSuggester": {
            "col": {
                "numFound": 1,
                "suggestions": [
                    {
                        "term": "In choosing Colors for candy, certain qualifications are necessary. First, they must not fade or change",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "payload": ""
                    }]}}}
}
```

Here's the relevant solrconfig.xml settings:

```
<searchComponent name="iiif_suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">ocrtext_suggest</str>
    <str name="contextField">is_page_of_ssim</str>
    <str name="field">ocrtext</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

And here are the field definitions in schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="ocrtext_suggest" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9]" replacement=" " />
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="ocrtext" type="ocrtext_suggest" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

Essentially, the `ocrtext_suggest` is modeled on the default Solr `textSpell` field type definition. However, I have observed that the field must have `stored="true"` in order for any results to be returned.

When I view the contents of the ocrtext field in the Solr GUI schema browser and click Load Term Info, the field appears to be tokenized into single terms. I don't understand how DocumentDictionaryFactory is storing the full field values.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39593671/returning-single-word-from-solr-suggester for a similar question

Answer (score 0):

try replacing this `<str name="lookupImpl">FreeTextLookupFactory</str>` for your requirement.